# show/hide drop down

Tags: javascript

here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE> New Document </TITLE>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("radio1").onchange = function() {
        if(this.checked == true) {
            document.getElementById("list1").style.visibility = "hidden";
            document.getElementById("list1").style.display = "none";
        }
    };

    document.getElementById("radio2").onchange = function() {
        if(this.checked == true) {
            document.getElementById("list1").style.visibility = "visible";
            document.getElementById("list1").style.display = "block";
        }
    };
</script>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

<form method = "post">

<br /><p id="first"><label>First Name:</label><input type="text" name="first" size="30" /></p>

<br /><p id="last"><label>Last Name:</label><input type="text" name="last" size="30" /></p>

<br /><p id="instructor"><label>Instructor:</label><select name="instructor">
<option value="instructor1">instructor1</option>
<option value="instructor2">instructor2</option></select></p>

<br /><p id="hospitalorientation"><label>Hospital Orientation:</label>
<div id='buttons'>
<label><input id="radio1" type="radio" name="hospital" /> Not Complete </label>
<label><input id="radio2" type="radio" name="hospital" /> Complete </label>
</div>
<div id="list1" style="display: none;">
<label>Month Complete:
<select>
    <option>January</option>
    <option>February</option>
    <option>March</option>
    <option>April</option>
    <option>May</option>
    <option>June</option>
    <option>July</option>
    <option>August</option>
    <option>September</option>
    <option>October</option>
    <option>November</option>
    <option>December</option>
</select>
</label>
</div>

</form>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I will have more fields like the hospital field, so i will need to do it more than one. I need a drop down to show when a certain radio button is selected. But everything i try in javascript doesnt work. I am new to javascript.

Answer (score 1):

I think its because the code is executed BEFORE the list is actually added to the document structure.
Encapsulate it in a window.onload handler like this:

```
...
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function()
{
    document.getElementById("radio1").onchange = function()
    {
        if(this.checked == true)
        {
            document.getElementById("list1").style.visibility = "hidden";
            document.getElementById("list1").style.display = "none";
        }
    };

    document.getElementById("radio2").onchange = function()
    {
        if(this.checked == true)
        {
            document.getElementById("list1").style.visibility = "visible";
            document.getElementById("list1").style.display = "block";
        }
    };
}
</script>
...
```

Lg
warappa

Answer (score 0):

as a side issue you dont need the `style.visibility...` line

one more thing:

Typically, its better to add event listeners using the attachEvent or addEventListener methods (allows more control, and multiple listeners for one action) like this:

```
function addEvent(el, eType, fn, uC) {
  if (el.addEventListener) {
    el.addEventListener(eType, fn, uC);
    return true;
  } 
  else if (el.attachEvent) {
    return el.attachEvent('on' + eType, fn);
  }
  else {
    el['on' + eType] = fn;
  }
}
```

and then just use

```
addEvent(
    document.getElementById("radio1"),
    "change",
    function(){
      if(this.checked == true){
            document.getElementById("list1").style.display = "none";
      }
    },
    false);
```

This is both cross-browser and better practice

Answer (score 0):

Your biggest issue here is that the javascript is going to execute prior to the radio buttons being created.  Therefore `document.getElementById(...)` is not going to find the element, as it doesn't exist.  Try adding your code to a function and having that function run onload of the body.

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait until your object (radio button load) Here is some code that works.  Or call the window.onload

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkEm() {
        if (document.getElementById("radio1").checked) {
            document.getElementById("list1").style.visibility = "hidden";
            document.getElementById("list1").style.display = "none";
        };

        if (document.getElementById("radio2").checked) {
            document.getElementById("list1").style.visibility = "visible";
            document.getElementById("list1").style.display = "block";
        };
    };
    </script>

 <label><input id="radio1" type="radio" name="hospital" onclick="checkEm()"  /> Not Complete </label>
<label><input id="radio2" type="radio" name="hospital" onclick="checkEm()" /> Complete </label>
```