# I need a javascript to search for a text in the page then hide a dropdown box

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, full-text-search, show-hide, replace

I need to be able to hide the drop down box if "X specific string" is found. Any ideas on how to do this I'll appreciate. I searched for hiding textbox/dropdown but I can't find a way to make it work by searching the whole page. Thanks

I have not picked any search and hide as it doesn't work.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6848797/show-hide-drop-down I've seen options as this one.

Comment: Show us what you tried, your javascript, html code.

Comment: Also: found where; in the document? In a text-box? In an iframe?

Comment: What part are you fighting with: Searching for the string, or hiding an element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To manipulate an element from JavaScript you need to somehow get a reference to it, which can be done in numerous ways - without any context to go on I'd suggest your best option is to make sure your select element has an `id` attribute:

```
<select id="myDropDown" name="whatever">
     <option>One</option>
     <option>Two</option>
</select>
```

...and then use `document.getElementById()`. Then to hide it you can update the appropriate style property:

```
document.getElementById("myDropDown").style.display = "none";
// OR
document.getElementById("myDropDown").style.visibility = "hidden";
```

Using `display:none` causes the browser to render the document as if the element didn't exist, i.e., it won't leave a space for it. Using `visibility:hidden` will make it invisible but there'll be an empty space on the page.

There is more than one way to to test for a particular string on the page, but one way is just to get all the content via the body element's `innerHTML` or `textContent` (or, in IE `innerText`) properties and then use `.indexOf()`:

```
var searchString = "some string",
    pageContent = document.body.innerHTML;

if (pageContent.indexOf(searchString) != -1) {
   document.getElementById("myDropDown").style.display = "none";
}
```

Where you place that code depends on when you want to do the test. You could put it in an `onload` handler if you want to do it without user input, otherwise put it in a click handler or something as appropriate.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/n8uA9/